# How to make the ViewRenderable size same as the detected Image to overlay exactly on it in ARCore Sceneform

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, arcore, sceneform

I have created a Augmented Images Android project.

Now I want to overlay a 2d png image on the detected image

How can I make sure that the overlay image size matches the detected image size